# Replace characters without opening Excel file

Tags: python, excel, shell, vbscript

I have a large Excel file (450mb+). I need to replace (,) -> (; or .) for one of my fastload scripts to work.  I am not able to open the file at all. Any script would actually involve opening the file, performing operation, saving and closing the file, in that order.

Will a VB script like that work here for the 450mb+ file, wherein the file is not opening only.

- Is there any VB script , Shell script, Python, Java etc I can write actually to perform the replacement(operation) without opening the Excel file?
- Or alternatively, is there any way of opening an Excel file that big
  and performing that operation.

Comment: you can turn to a programming language, like java, python, they have libraries to handle Excel files.

Comment: Is it classic Excel (`.xls`), new Excel (`.xslx`), or Excel-compatible CSV (`.csv`) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux environment (which you might since you mention shell script as one of your options) then just use `sed` in a terminal or Putty:

`sed -i .bak 's/,/;/g' yourfile.excel`

Sed streams the text without loading the entire file at once.

`-i` will make changes to your original file but providing `.bak` will create a copy named `yourfile.excel.bak` first